# Canvas game where you dodge projectiles

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**The Problem**

I am creating a game where you have to dodge projectiles, for every projectile you miss you gain 1 point. At the moment I have it so every projectile that hits you, the score goes up.

**The Question**

How can I change this so that the score goes up for every projectile that misses you?

**The Code**

```
        function init() {

            level = 1;
            total_projectiles = 0;
            projectiles = [];

            c = document.getElementById("c");
            ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = "#ff6600";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 600);

            c.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
                //moving over the canvas.
                var bounding_box = c.getBoundingClientRect();
                player.x = (e.clientX - bounding_box.left) * (c.width / bounding_box.width) - player_img.width / 2;
            }, false);

            setupProjectiles(); 
            requestAnimationFrame(tick);
        }

        function setupProjectiles() {
            var max_projectiles = level * projectiles_per_level;
            while (projectiles.length < max_projectiles) {
                initProjectile(projectiles.length);
            }
        }

        function initProjectile(index) {
            var max_speed = max_speed_per_level * level;
            var min_speed = min_speed_per_level * level;
            projectiles[index] = {
                x: Math.round(Math.random() * (width - 2 * projectile_w)) + projectile_w,
                y: -projectile_h,
                v: Math.round(Math.random() * (max_speed - min_speed)) + min_speed,
                delay: Date.now() + Math.random() * delay
            }
            total_projectiles++;
        }

        function collision(projectile) {
            if (projectile.y + projectile_img.height < player.y + 74) {
                return false;
            }
            if (projectile.y > player.y + 74) {
                return false;
            }
            if (projectile.x + projectile_img.width < player.x + 177) {
                return false;
            }
            if (projectile.x > player.x + 177) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        function maybeIncreaseDifficulty() {
            level = Math.max(1, Math.ceil(player.score / 10));
            setupProjectiles();
        }

        function tick() {
            var i;
            var projectile;
            var dateNow = Date.now();
            c.width = c.width;
            for (i = 0; i < projectiles.length; i++) {
                projectile = projectiles[i];
                if (dateNow > projectile.delay) {
                    projectile.y += projectile.v;
                    if (collision(projectile)) {
                        initProjectile(i);
                        player.score++;
                    } else if (projectile.y > height) {
                        initProjectile(i);
                    } else {
                        ctx.drawImage(projectile_img, projectile.x, projectile.y);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please narrow your included code down to where the problem appears to occur.

Comment: I'm not reading through your code.  But you should make sure you destroy the projectile when it hits the player; any projectile not destroyed will eventually reach some position that indicates it will never hit the player (e.g. the bottom of the screen if projectiles always move down).  Use that trigger to increment the score.

Comment: I have narrowed it down a bit, including only projectile code and player code

Comment: I didn't read the code but I've an idea for you. make a collision area surrounding the player, bigger than the player , now if a "bullet" enter and quit this area without hitting the player it's dodged!

Comment: I posted an answer showing how to test for "near misses". **However**, I must comment that you have asked 10 questions requesting help with your game in the last week. You might take more time trying to solve your issues before turning to Stackoverflow for help because it's starting to feel like you're having us program your game for you. :-// If you're just learning, that's cool, but instead maybe you want to start with a simpler project until you gain the basic skills. Just saying ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can test "near misses" like this:**

- Add a `nearRadius` property to the projectile object. The `nearRadius` is larger than the projectile's actual radius and is used to hit-test when the projectile passes near the player.
- Add an `isNear` property to the projectile object. `isNear` is a true/false property indicating if the `nearRadius` is colliding with the player.
- When the projectile's `isNear` property changes from true to false, the projectile has passed the player in a near miss. You can increase the player's score when this happens.

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var player={x:cw/2,y:50,radius:15,score:0};
var projectile={x:-30,y:30,radius:5,nearRadius:35,isNear:false}
var gameOver=false;

ctx.textAlign='center';
ctx.textBaseline='middle';
ctx.font='14px verdana';

draw();

$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    // player
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(player.x,player.y,player.radius,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle='green';
    ctx.fill();
    // players score
    ctx.fillStyle='white';
    ctx.fillText(player.score,player.x,player.y);
    // projectile
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(projectile.x,projectile.y,projectile.radius,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle='red';
    ctx.fill();
    // projectile near 
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(projectile.x,projectile.y,projectile.nearRadius,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.strokeStyle=projectile.isNear?'green':'red';
    ctx.stroke();
    // if game over
    if(gameOver){
        ctx.font='30px verdana';
        ctx.fillStyle='blue';
        ctx.fillText('Game Over',cw/2,35);
    }
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
    if(gameOver){return;}
    
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    projectile.x=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    projectile.y=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

    var dx=projectile.x-player.x;
    var dy=projectile.y-player.y;

    // test projectile hits player
    var rr=projectile.radius+player.radius;
    gameOver=(dx*dx+dy*dy)<(rr*rr);
    
    // test projectile nearly misses player
    var rr=projectile.nearRadius+player.radius;
    var isNearNow=(dx*dx+dy*dy)<(rr*rr);
    if(projectile.isNear && !isNearNow){
        player.score++;
    }
    projectile.isNear=isNearNow;
    draw();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Move red projectile with mouse<br>Score when outer ring passes by player.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```